# Submit form with out page refresh in Servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $('.ibutton').click(function() 
    {
           var ajaxdata=$("#country").val();
           var value = "country="+ajaxdata;            
           $.ajax({
                        url: "saveIt",         
                        type: "POST",                           
                        data: value,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){ 
                                      alert("load success");              
                                }
                    });return false;  
    });   
});

</script>
```

Friends, i followed every thing but its not working, upon submit, am unable to send the servlet request,  saveIt is my url pattern,pls help me.

Comment: One tip, send the value as dictionary {'country':value}

Comment: what is `.ibutton`? is it of type `submit` or something else?

Comment: ibutton is <input type="button" id="ibutton" class="ibutton" value="Save"/>

Comment: How does it not work? What happens? Any errors or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ibutton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // add preventDefault()
        var ajaxdata = $("#country").val();

        // don't send data like this
        // var value = "country=" + ajaxdata;
        // try like below, as an object
        var value = {'countr' : ajaxdata};

        $.ajax({
            url: "saveIt",
            type: "POST",
            data: value,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("load success");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

#### Note

Try tho debug the `POST` request through firebug or such type of debugger that its working properly.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the problem with binding to the click event is that hitting "Enter" on the keyboard still causes a page refresh

Comment: yeah am getting the out put only if i put comment to type as
//type: "post",
if i remove the comment, am getting the error in firebug its saying ------405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Comment: @John then send data via `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to prevent the default behavior on form submit event.

```
$( function () {
$("#ajax-form").submit(function(event){
  // fire Ajax
  $.post( "/saveIt", { country: $("#country").val() }, function (data) {} );
  event.preventDefault();
});
} );
```

Comment: Have you removed your click listener? What does it mean no response? Check the Network panel in your Chrome inspector/Firebug to see if the request is sent. Also check the console for errors